# How to keep quotes in ant property ("")？

Tags: jenkins, ant

I was debugging jenkins + ant + jmeter framework in the process of finding jenkins pass with double quotation marks ("xxx") to jmeter when double quotes ("") can not be displayed, become xxx, i see build.xml and debug Found that there may be ant to jmeter process there is a problem? See below

Here parameters are quotation marks ("MallID")
[image]

[image][image]

```html
<target name="run" depends="clean, show-test-properties">
  
  <!-- create dir -->
  <mkdir  dir="${test.result.path}"/>
  <mkdir  dir="${test.log.path}"/>
  
  <jmeter
   jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
      testplan ="${test.plan.path}"
      resultlog="${test.result.path}/result.jtl"
   jmeterlogfile="${test.log.path}/jmeter.log"
   >
   <jvmarg value="${jvm.arg}"/> <!-- modify as you wish -->
   
   <!-- Force suitable defaults -->
   <!-- values for UDV -->
   <property name="api.url" value="${api.url}"/>
   <property name="api.fieldparam" value="${api.fieldparam}"/>
   <property name="api.bodyparam" value="${api.bodyparam}"/>

  </jmeter>
 </target>
```

[image]

Here all the quotation marks("") marks are canceled (MallID) why?
[image]

Comment: i want to keep quotes in ant property ("")

Comment: This is not a limitation of Ant, but actually a general limitation of *Java's* handling of command line system properties. You can set properties containing quotes in a properties file or in your script, but as far as I know, it is impossible to send quotes through command line because Java will always remove them.

Comment: @blue did you solve you problem ? I got same issue

Comment: @HarshPatel  I hava solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting anything in Ant, it requires you to use double quotations (i.e. "") in order to specify the value. If you wish to keep the quotations in the value, may I suggest trying the following:

```
<property name="api.url" value="&quot;${api.url}&quot;"/>
<property name="api.fieldparam" value="&quot;${api.fieldparam}&quot;"/>
<property name="api.bodyparam" value="&quot;${api.bodyparam}&quot;"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, to solve my problem! :) @calvin.lau

Comment: @blue No problem at all. I suggest referring to a chart that illustrates all XML special characters in the future in case you find yourself in a similar situation:

`< &lt;
> &gt;
" &quot;
& &amp;
' &apos;`

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this string today. "[{"assert":"m","fieldname":"v","max":0,"min":0},{"assert":"‌​g","fieldname":"c","‌​max":0,"min":0}] "and use the ant argument" "for example:"<property name="api.fieldarray" value="&quot;${api.fieldarray}&quot;"/>"But still did not keep double quotes" ", do not know why?@calvin.lau